# Local variable referenced before assignment in if statement

Tags: python-3.x

This is the code that I am working on right now:

```
def getWinner(userChoice, computerChoice):

    if userChoice == "rock" and computerChoice == "scissors":
       winner = userChoice
    elif userChoice == "paper" and computerChoice == "rock":
       winner = userChoice
    elif userChoice == "scissors" and computerChoice == "paper":
       winner = userChoice
    elif userChoice == "rock" and computerChoice == "paper":
       winner = computerChoice
    elif userChoice == "paper" and computerChoice == "scissors":
      winner = computerChoice
    elif userChoice == "scissors" and computerChoice == "rock":
      winner = computerchoice
    elif userChoice == computerChoice:
      winner = "It's a tie."
return(winner)

userChoice = input("Enter your choice:")
computerChoice = print(getComputerChoice())
winnerOfGame = getWinner(userChoice, computerChoice)
print(winnerOfGame)
```

I am trying to set up a rock, paper, scissors game, but every time I try to run this function, it returns with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Python34/idk 2.py", line 45, in <module>
    winnerOfGame = getWinner(userChoice, computerChoice)
   File "C:/Python34/idk 2.py", line 41, in getWinner
    return(winner)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'winner' referenced before assignment
```

I have tried assigning a global variable, but nothing seems to be working when I try to fix it. When I do other if statements like this, I do not have issues with the variable being referenced before assignment, and I am doing nothing differently.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to declare `winner` at the beginning of the function. You don't need global variable here. You also need to specify what should be the result if the `userChoice` or `computerChoice` have none of the expected values. You should return an error probably.

```
def getWinner(userChoice, computerChoice):
    winner = "" #***************
    if userChoice == "rock" and computerChoice == "scissors":
        winner = userChoice
    elif userChoice == "paper" and computerChoice == "rock":
        winner = userChoice
    elif userChoice == "scissors" and computerChoice == "paper":
        winner = userChoice
    elif userChoice == "rock" and computerChoice == "paper":
        winner = computerChoice
    elif userChoice == "paper" and computerChoice == "scissors":
       winner = computerChoice
    elif userChoice == "scissors" and computerChoice == "rock":
       winner = computerchoice
    elif userChoice == computerChoice:
       winner = "It's a tie."
    else:
       winner = "Wrong input! Try again" #************
    return winner

userChoice = input("Enter your choice:")
computerChoice = print(getComputerChoice())
winnerOfGame = getWinner(userChoice, computerChoice)
print(winnerOfGame)
```

Comment: if the `winner` in the `else` statement is defined, why would one need to declare winner before the `if-else` block?

Comment: That's correct. If you have an `else` statement that defines `winner`, there's no need in defining it beforehand. But if you don't have `else` (as the original question), then the declaration is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get occurs when either of the two arguments has a value that is different from the three expected values (could be a simple spelling mistake). In that case `winner` never gets defined, and so when you get to `return winner`, Python does not know what you are talking about :-)

So you should check for such a condition.

As we are at it, you could simplify your code a bit. I suggest using an array with the three possible values. The player that has the value that precedes the other immediately (round robin wise) wins:

```
def getWinner(userChoice, computerChoice):
    options = ["rock", "scissors", "paper"]
    # check that the two arguments have valid values:
    try:
        userChoiceId = options.index(userChoice);
    except ValueError:
        return "invalid choice: {}".format(userChoice)
    try:
        computerChoiceId = options.index(computerChoice)
    except ValueError:
        return "invalid choice: {}".format(computerChoice)
    # now there are only three outcomes:
    if userChoiceId == computerChoiceId:
        winner = "It's a tie."
    elif (userChoiceId + 1) % 3 == computerChoiceId: 
        winner = userChoice
    else:
        winner = computerChoice
    return winner
```